# Query array by stored index in document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this

```
{
    "status": {
        "current": 0,
        "priority": [{
            "operationName": "PHOTO",
            "status": "WAITING"
        },
        {
            "operationName": "DESIGN",
            "status": "NOTARRIVED"
        },
        {
            "operationName": "COLOR_SEPARATION",
            "status": "NOTARRIVED"
        }]
    }
}
```

and want to query on data like this

```
{
    "status.priority.$status.current.operationName": {
        $in: ['SERVICES', 'PHOTO']
    }
}
```

when I query like this

```
{
    "status.priority.0.operationName": {
        $in: ['SERVICES', 'PHOTO']
    }
}
```

it returns the data needed as the `'PHOTO'` is the current operation.

I need to query based on an index of the array and this index is stored in the document in `status.current`

any hint?

**UPDATE**
After question solved I want to optimize it.

Comment: Please be more specific what you want to achieve

Comment: want to query on some index and that index stored in db in "$status.current"
I want to use this index in my query like `"status.priority.3.operationName"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$arrayElemAt` with `$expr` in 3.6.

Something like

```
db.colname.find(
 {"$expr":{
   "$in":[
     {"$arrayElemAt":["$status.priority.operationName","$status.current"]},
     ['DESIGN', 'COLOR_SEPARATION', 'PHOTO']
   ]
 }}
)
```

Comment: How to optimize it using an index?

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use `aggregation`

```
db.collname.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      priority: { $arrayElemAt: ["$status.priority", '$status.current'] },
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "priority.operationName": {
        $in: ['DESIGN', 'COLOR_SEPARATION', 'PHOTO']
      }

    }
  }
])
```

This will work for you.

Result will be like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6b656818883ec018d1542d"),
    "priority" : {
        "operationName" : "PHOTO",
        "status" : "WAITING"
    }
}
```

Comment: How to optimize it using an index?